# is it possible to send value from <a4j:support> to bean

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

```
<rich:tree switchType="client" value="#{Bean.tree}" var="one">
                                <rich:treeNode>

                                    <h:commandLink value="#{one.item1}"
                                        action="#{Bean.getItem()}"
                                        style="color:blue;text-decoration:none;"
                                        title="Click here to view details">
                                        <f:param name="ids" value="#{one.id}">          
                                        </f:param>
                                    </h:commandLink>


                                    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="productInformation"

                                                                        action="#{Bean.getItem()}"/>
                               </rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>

<rich:panel id="productInformation">

</rich:panel>
```

hi I have a page in that tree structure will be present if i click on the link the corresponding action should be performed but by using h:commandlink the whole page will be refreshed.So Iam going for  I have a problem here in h:commandlink i was able to transfer the parameter to bean by using f:param but by using  how can I acess the value to bean please help me out iam new to jsf.

Comment: yes do u have any idea of how we can send from a4j to bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the solution by using a4j:commandlink tag and passing the parameter from a function.
<
a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" value="#{item.Description}(#{item.name})"
action="#{Bean.getProductLink(item.paramID)}" style="color:blue;text-decoration:none;" title="#{item.productDescription}"  reRender="addproductGuidForms"/>

is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JSF2 there is no need to pass with `f:param` just pass it in method args

```
action="#{Bean.getItem(one.id)}"
```

b.t.w you better rename the method name into `action="#{Bean.retrieveItem(one.id)}"`

Comment: This is not specific to JSF 2.x. This is specific to EL 2.2. In other words, it would work as good with JSF 1.x as long as you're using EL 2.2.

Comment: @BalusC, I know its related to EL 2.2 , I was just assuming that if he uses JSF 2 he will use EL 2.2 too (of course my assumption might be wrong :))

Comment: <h:outputText value="#{one.item1}"
style="color:blue;text-decoration:none;"
title="Click here to view details">
<a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="productInformation"
action="#{Bean.getItem(one.id)}" />
</h:outputText>                                                        I have replaced the code with H:commandlink to H:outputtext but it is still not working unable to retrieve the above one.id in bean

Comment: that's what I have meant : `<h:commandLink value="#{one.item1}"
 action="#{Bean.retrieveItem(one.id)}"
 style="color:blue;text-decoration:none;"
 title="Click here to view details">
</h:commandLink>`

Comment: Hi Daniel Thanks for your reply....... the main problem is I want to replace the H:commandlink with a4j:support because while using h:commandlink tag the whole page is refreshing but i want only part of the page to be refreshed so for displaying iam going for h:outputtext and if I click on any link the corresponding value should be passed to the bean by using a4j:support.

Comment: since you are using JSF2 you can use `f:ajax` to partially render element on page, like this `<h:commandLink value="#{one.item1}" action="#{Bean.retrieveItem(one.id)}" style="color:blue;text-decoration:none;" title="Click here to view details">
 <f:ajax render="productInformation"/>
</h:commandLink>`